# Bind the model to partialview on post

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have partialviews inside a view. I am rendering the partial views using RenderAction Method

```
<div class="report">
        @{ Html.RenderAction("ActionName", "ControllerName");}
    </div>
```

in the partial view I have a post back where in I update the Model and send it to the partial view using

```
return PartialView("_PartialView");
```

The whole of the view gets refreshed

> The viewmodel of the parent page is different to the viewmodel of the partialpages

Is there a way I can only refresh the partialview on the partialview postback ?

Comment: You should look into using AJAX instead if you just want to update a portion of a web page.

Comment: For that you need to use ajax and update an DOM of the existing page

Comment: Thanks guys.. 
I have used Ajax and trying to fetch and bind the updated model but the whole form is getting refreshed

Answer (score 0):

Try Url.Action instead of  Html.RenderAction

```
<div class="report">
    @{ Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName");}
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried this , but does not work as the partial view has a post back.